# Bibliographic entries contained in second file not found

Tags: biblatex, biber

For the following:

```
\usepackage[notes,isbn=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{main.bib}
\addbibresource{secondary.bib}
```

There are four entries in the first file and two in the second.  Biber doesn't seem to be able to find any of the entries in the second bib file, although it reports a total of 6 keys.  Note the absence of any reference to secondary.bib

```
INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
...
INFO - Found 6 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing bib sectiong 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'main.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Finished Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'main.bib'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'main.bib' for section 0
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'source1' (section 0)
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'source2' (section 0)
INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'level = 4' with 'level = 2'
INFO - Sorting list 'MAIN' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'level = 4' with 'level = 2'
INFO - Sorting list 'SHORTHANDS' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
...
INFO - WARNINGS: 2
```

If it matters, I am using TexPad

*EDIT*

bcf:

```
  <bcf:bibdata section="0">
    <bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">main.bib</bcf:datasource>
    <bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">secondary.bib</bcf:datasource>
  </bcf:bibdata>
  <bcf:section number="0">
    <bcf:citekey>main1</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey>main2</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey>main3</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey>main4</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey>source1</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey>source2</bcf:citekey>
  </bcf:section>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In my experiment there's no problem. However I have `biber` version 1.5. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I installed everything using MacTex

Comment: You should run TeX Live Utility and do a thorough upgrade.

Comment: Good to know about that.  I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: That fixed it.  Too bad MacTex doesn't update itself when you install.

Comment: MacTeX will install updates within a given vintage, but won't install an entirely new vintage automatically.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug of your Biber. Since the current version of Biber is 1.5, try first of all upgrading your TeX distribution to the latest snapshot.

Since you're using MacTeX, ensure you have installed the 2012 version and run “TeX Live Utility” that you find in `/Applications/TeX`. Update all the available packages and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Actually that did not solve my problem.  I had accidentally pasted the sources from the second file into the first, so they showed up.  When I removed them, I got errors about missing references again, even with Biber 1.5

Comment: The problem seems to be with Texpad.  Running the generic pdflatex and biber commands do work.